# Delegates in OSX with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, swift2

i'm trying to get delegates working for an OSX app with Swift.

```
import Cocoa

class loginViewController: NSViewController {
    weak var delegate: recordViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do view setup here.
      delegate?.trySomething()
      self.delegate?.trySomething()
      self.delegate?.testPrint("hello, is it me your looking for")
    }
}

protocol recordViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func testPrint(val: String)
  func trySomething()
}

class recordViewController: NSViewController, recordViewControllerDelegate {

  func testPrint(val: String) {
    print(val)
  }

  func trySomething() {
    print("aaa")
  }
}
```

Everything looks right but testPrint & trySomething never get called, added breakpoints but nothing happens.

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Driving me round the bend...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it takes two protocols to set up a delegate pattern see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html If you would like an example, just ask :D.

Comment: absolutely, if you could?

Comment: I am away from my computer right now, so I will post one in about an hour if no one else does.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: so you don't need an example right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `self.delegate` is `nil` right? so you should assign an object first. 
Try it like this, here is code from my `AppDelegate.swift` Cocoa demo project:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        //This is not a good practice to call viewDidLoad directly
        //Its just a demonstration of quick way to call `recordViewControllerDelegate` protocol functions
        let vc = loginViewController()
        vc.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

//MARK:- login VC
class loginViewController: NSViewController {
    weak var delegate: recordViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let recVC = recordViewController()
        self.delegate = recVC

        delegate?.trySomething()
        self.delegate?.trySomething()
        self.delegate?.testPrint("hello, is it me your looking for")
    }
}

protocol recordViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func testPrint(val: String)
    func trySomething()
}

class recordViewController: NSViewController, recordViewControllerDelegate {

    func testPrint(val: String) {
        print(val)
    }

    func trySomething() {
        print("aaa")
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, I can see printed logs. 
Please note that in my case I'm calling `viewDidLoad` function directly - just to show you how delegate pattern works. 
Apple doesn't recommend to call it directly. The right way is to present view controller and `viewDidLoad` function will be called by OS X SDK APIs.

Comment: the last two lines were out of desperation, i found an example that suggested doing that, but at the very least: delegate?.trySomething() should have fired

Comment: You have `weak var delegate: recordViewControllerDelegate?` optional property. You should init it and assign to it delegate object, which will be responsible for `testPrint()`.

Comment: thanks, tried adding self.delegate = recordViewController() but still no go. am i missing a library?

Comment: Thanks, eventually got it working by removing weak on var delegate: recordViewController? and self.delegate = recordViewController()

Comment: Oh, thats great, but be careful, removing `weak` attribute from delegate might cause retain cycles. More info about `Automatic Reference Counting` from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: Thanks i managed to re-add weak and it's still working. thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding!